# Will Redis queue up hset commands for numerous requests?

Tags: ruby, database, redis

Say I have 100 requests coming in every second and for each query, a hash value needs to be extracted and then, the same hash needs to be updated sort of like:

redis.hget 'value', 'user-123'
redis.hset 'value', 'user-123', JSON.generate({:number_of_visits => 15})

What happens if there's a ton of read\writes per second?

Will redis just queue up both the hget and hset commands and they'll all execute in order they came in? Will it slow down the hgets the more commands come in?

Comment: Redis is pretty fast by way; under normal circumstances it can easily handle thousands of commands per second with no issues other than the actual network latency (ie the time it takes to send the commands to the redis instance and back), so in the case you describe you would be fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Redis uses a single thread to process commands, so the commands will be processed in the order they arrive.

Some docs [here](http://www.enjoythearchitecture.com/redis-architecture),

> At its roots, Redis is a single-threaded server. This means that a
>   single thread reads incoming connections using an event-based paradigm
>   such as epoll, kqueue and select. When a specific event occurs on a
>   file descriptor, it processes them and write back responses. This UML
>   sequence diagram shows how a command received by a client is processed
>   internally by Redis:

If you send commands at a rate faster than redis can handle them, the commands will queue in redis, and the clients will see increase latency, as they wait for their commands to be dequeued and processed.  This will affect both hset and hget commands.

Comment: Actually, if you saturate Redis with traffic, it will queue in the socket buffers, more than in Redis itself. When the socket buffers are full, the TCP flow control will slow down the clients. If Redis was completely queuing the incoming traffic, it would be a serious vulnerability (memory explosion in case of saturation).